# select application desfire 7816

Tags: select, nfc

I have a DESFIRE EV1 card(NOT BLANK) when I want to select application(ISO 7816 mentioned in DESFIRE 7816 manual ) I get "6A 82" response
I use this APDU for selecting application by it's 3-byte identifier .
  `-> 00 A4 04 00 03 XX XX XX`
  `<- 6a 82`
I can select this application by wrapped APDU of native DESfire commands .

---

there is an another issue , I have problem with EXTERNAL AUTHENTICATION , I should define algorithm id byte, i want to select "3DES diversify"
how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select application you have to execute below command:

90 5A 00 00 03 `010000` 00

where application id is "010000"